# El uso del artículo indefinido después de "me gusta/me interesa, etc."

Tags: gramática, artículos

Soy consciente de que por varias razones no es posible omitir el artículo definido en una oración como "*Me gustan **las** flores*".

No obstante, ¿podemos usar el artículo indefinido después de "me gusta(n)", "me interesa(n)" y después de otros verbos con la misma estructura (encantar, importar, etc.)? Es decir, ¿tanto en singular (un, una) como en plural (unos, unas)?

Traté de encontrar unos ejemplos con el artículo indefinido. Principalmente se usa el artículo definido, pero logré encontrar algunos ejemplos abajo:

*Me gustaría **un** sándwich*

*Me gustarían **unas** sugerencias para discutir con los padres*

*A ti te gusta **una** casa pequeña que hay en Toledo.*

*A mí me gusta **un** restaurante que está cerca de mi casa.*

*Me gusta **una** religión doctrinal.*

*A mí me gusta **una** mujer con un poco de carne en sus huesos.*

*No me interesa **una** respuesta de política interna, sino una respuesta de principios, desde una perspectiva comunitaria.*

De todos modos, me parece que el uso del artículo definido es mucho más común.

Comment: A mí me gustan mayores!  Con adjetivo detrás sí que puedes omitir artículo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que podemos, lo que ocurre es que cambia el significado de la frase.

> Me gusta una religión doctrinal

no es lo mismo que

> Me gusta la religión doctrinal

En el segundo caso estamos implicando que hay una única religión doctrinal.

O, si decimos

> Me gustaría el sándwich

Es natural que la respuesta sea ¿Cuál? (a menos que sólo haya un único sándwich en el menú)

Los artículos indefinidos dejan claro que no estamos hablando de un único ejemplar concreto, y los definidos justo lo contrario.