# El omitir los artículos antes de los adjetivos después de "Me gusta"

Tags: gramática, artículos

En esa respuesta [El uso del artículo indefinido después de "me gusta/me interesa, etc."](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39330/23475) leí:
"***A mí me gustan mayores**!  Con adjetivo detrás sí que puedes omitir artículo!*"

No lo sabía antes. Y sí, abajo están unos ejemplos como el de arriba:

En el título y en la letra de la canción "***Me gustan bonitas***" by Kvrass

En la canción "Quisiera Dejarte" by Oniel Anubis:

"*…Quisiera dejarte eh eh eh
Pero es que **a mi me gustan malas***"

¿Es posible dar más ejemplos del uso de los adjetivos sin artículo después de los verbos del tipo gustar?

¿En qué circunstancias es común decir así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según mi experiencia, este uso es más habitual precisamente hablando sobre el tipo de personas que te gustan y en muchos casos tiene un deje ligeramente explícito.

Otro uso sería, por ejemplo, con la comida.

- Me gusta bien frita (la carne)
- Me gusta fuerte y azucarado (el café)
- etc.